# how to use freeform entry_id on different pages for displaying the result from freeform entries?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I get the entry id and now wanna to display the result on different page for a particular item and all the related information with it.

but not displaying the result as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear but I believe you are looking to have this for your form tag:

```
{exp:freeform:form return="template_group/template/%%entry_id%%"}
    Form content goes here.
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

The return parameter with that value in the third segment passes along the entry_id of the submission in the URI. Then you can use the freeform entries tag on your submission template like this:

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_3}"}
    Submission content goes here.
    {freeform:author}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

[Freeform entries tag functions](https://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/) just like the channel entries tag.